# CFillFormat for powerpoint 2010

Tags: c++, powerpoint, office-2010

I'm using C++ to create a Powerpoint 2010 slide (in Windows 7).
I have a picture in a .bmp file that I'd like to fill the CShape.
So the code does this:

```
_variant_t vPicName= L"MyPicture1";
CShape picShape(slideshapes.Item(vPicName));
CString fullBitmapFilePath = "C:\MyCode\MyPicture.bmp";
CFillFormat picFill(picShape.get_Fill());
picFill.UserPicture(fullBitmapFilePath);
```

The shape gets drawn in the powerpoint as a green box, but it doesn't fill with the picture.
This same exact code works with Office 2003 on XP. Any tips?
Thank you